# OpenTok requires android.hardware.camera.autofocus?

Tags: android, cordova, opentok, autofocus, tokbox

I'm using the [Tokbox/OpenTok Cordova Plugin](https://github.com/opentok/cordova-plugin-opentok) in my app (which internally uses the native OpenTok Android SDK). But after uploading my apks to GooglePlay i've noticed that some users may not install the app since it sets `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="true" />` which is a problem for older Android devices (e.g. Samsung GT-P5100 / Samsung Galaxy Tab2 10.1).

My question: Is `autofocus` really required to use opentok or could it be optional so all users can access the new version?

The official [requirements](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/android/#requirements) for the Android SDK state:

*The OpenTok Android SDK works with any Android 4.1+ device (Jelly Bean, API Level 16) that has a camera (for publishing video) and adequate CPU and memory support.*

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great point! Autofocus is not a requirement for the OpenTok Android SDK. I've updated the plugin.xml to the following: 
`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />`

Here's a link to the updated Cordova-OpenTok-Plugin which uses iOS and Android 2.12.0 SDKs: https://github.com/opentok/cordova-plugin-opentok

Comment: Thanks, this actually helps a lot!